# Using AutoMapper to create a new instance of an generic object

Tags: c#, generics, automapper

I'm trying to simulate the behavior of saving an entity within a repository (using a generic T parameter). For the Save() method, I need to store a new instance of the given entity rather than the actual one.

I thought about using AutoMapper for this:

```
    public void Save(T entity)
    {
        var newEntity = Mapper.Map<T, T>(entity);
        this.AddOrUpdate(newEntity);
    }
```

The problem is that newEntity is actually the same instance as entity and whatever change I make to a property of entity will impact the stored newEntity.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think you need to create a new object. AddOrUpdate takes care of it.

Comment: BTW method name is Save and you are performing add or edit operation. This is not good from clean code perspective. If I were you, I would add two methods, Add and Update. Save remains common to save all changes in the context.

Comment: No, AddOrUpdate doesn't, it's basically a method that I have written to to handle the logic of adding or updating a given entity.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry, made few assumption (thought you are using EF). Silly me! How about separating your call to two as I suggested above?

Comment: Thanks fore the advice, i'll think about it when i'll enter the refactoring phase, but for now on, i would like to make the code work

Comment: Can you show us AddOrUpdate() method code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be like this:

```
public void Save(T entity)
{
  Mapper.CreateMap<T, T>();
  var newEntity = Mapper.Map<T, T>(entity);
}
```

Comment: That made the trick, i missed Mapper.CreateMap<T,T>(). Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is probably wise to separate your CreateMap statements from the actual usage. Perhaps stick it in a profile and bootstrap early on.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new instance of T via Activator, and then copy the values from your existing entity to the newly created entity:

```
var newEntity = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
Mapper.Map(entity, newEntity);
```

Comment: Only is the object has a default constructor.